# Why Php explode is echoing but can't post

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have exploded timestamp2w to date and time. I can post the date to the database but the time isn't posting, but if i echo it, it is showing the time. i want to post that time to the db.

```
  $timestamp3=$_POST['timestamp'];
  $timestamp3x=explode(" ",$timestamp3);
  $timestamp=$timestamp3x[0];
  $timestamp3=$timestamp3x[1];

  $datetime=$_POST['$timestamp3'];

  $transactiondate =date("Y-m-d");
  $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
   $equipmentid = $_GET['id']; 
   echo $timestamp3;
$sql="Insert into tbl_booking(equipmentid,book_to,book_from,transactiondate,user_booked,datetime)VALUES('$equipmentid','$timestamp2','$timestamp','$transactiondate','$userid','$datetime')";
```

Comment: Erh, you haven't defined any connection to the database nor are you executing the query.

Comment: You're setting `$timestamp3`, but putting `$timestamp2` in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have time value in `$timestamp3` and you are sending `$timestamp2` to `mysql query` so change your query like below

```
$sql="Insert into tbl_booking(equipmentid,book_to,book_from,transactiondate,user_booked,datetime)VALUES('$equipmentid','$timestamp3','$timestamp','$transactiondate','$userid','$datetime')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you're echoing $timestamp3 variable, but in the query I can see $timestamp2!